# How to read childrens from a firebase database using FirebaseListAdapter in java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new in Firebase. So, i have a database structure like this:

[image]

and want to display those generated id's into a listview. I'm using FirebaseListAdapter. Here is my code:

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Firebase").child("Users");
    firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String string, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(string);
        }
    };
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

This is my User class:

```
class User {
private String userName;
private String email;

    void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}
    String getUserName() {return userName;}

    void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    String getEmail() {return email;}
}
```

When i copile this, i get this error: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to show what's inside that User object.

Comment: How can i do that? I have just added the User class. But remember, i need only those id's in my listview. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `populateView` method implementation to

```
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<User>(this, User.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, User user, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        String userKey = this.getRef(position).getKey();
        textView.setText(userKey);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to display in my listview the username. I want to display what is inside the User object, those id's.

Comment: I tried this but i get the same error: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String` Do you have any other idea? Thanks

Comment: @AlexM.again, I have updated my answer. This should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a `FirebaseListAdapter<Map>` instead of `FirebaseListAdapter<String>`. Your code would become something like this (didn't compile it though, that's up to you ;-)

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Firebase").child("Users");
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Map>(this, Map.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Map users, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(users.getKey());
    }
};
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to display in my listview the username. I want to display what is inside the User object, those id's