# Filter and Order the firebase data in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following is my firebase database structure. 
[image]

The following is the method that I get the data from firebase database to the recycler view. However, there is an unique id(red oval) in the child part. How can I go after the unique id and filter the data using the key "category"? Also, I want to order them in acensding order but firebase does not provide a method for that. Where can I get the list of data and reverse them? Please give me some helps. Thank you very much.

```
    mFilterDatabse = mDatabase.orderByChild("category").equalTo(categoryResult);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(

            Product.class,
            R.layout.product_row,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            mFilterDatabse
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, final Product model, int position) {

            Log.d(TAG, "loading view " + position);
            final String product_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProductImage());
            viewHolder.setUid(model.getUid());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent productDetailIntent = new Intent();
                    productDetailIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ProductDetailActivity.class);
                    productDetailIntent.putExtra("product_id", product_id);
                    Log.d(TAG + " product_id", product_id);
                    productDetailIntent.putExtra("colorNo", model.getColorNo());
                    Log.d(TAG + " colorNo", model.getColorNo() + "");
                    startActivity(productDetailIntent);
                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG, "finish loading view");
        }
    };

    mProductList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    private Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), FontManager.APP_FONT);

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        TextView product_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.p_title);
        product_title.setText(productName);
        product_title.setTypeface(customTypeface);
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        TextView product_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.p_desc);
        product_desc.setText(description);
        product_desc.setTypeface(customTypeface);
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        TextView product_username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.p_username);
        product_username.setText(uid);
        product_username.setTypeface(customTypeface);
    }

    public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image) {
        final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "image loading success !");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.d(TAG, "image loading error !");
                Picasso.with(ctx)
                        .load(image)
                        .resize(100, 100)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(post_image);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `push()` method to generate the unique keys, is the moment in which you can get the keys. Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Product).push();
String pushedKey = ref.getKey(); // We can do whatever you want with them
```

Because of the unique ids, the items are already ordered by date (ascending order). If you want to order descending you need to use a `TIMESTAMP` like this: `-1 * ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. Here is also the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) which will help you do more than that. You will be able to `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()` or `orderByValue()` and also `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `equalTo()` or to use intervals like: `startAt()` and `endAt()`.
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: But this means that I have to get the key when I create them? How to do that if I am not the creator? Also, would you mind to give me more further example about the TIMESTAMP like this: -1 * ServerValue.TIMESTAMP? Thank you very much.

Comment: Than you need to put a `listener` on the `Product` node, iterate over all childrens, get the id's like this: `String pushedKey = this.getRef(position).getKey();` than do wahtever you want with them. 
Regarding `-1 * ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, you first need to set a `TIMESTAMP` for each product. `-1 *` creates the negative `TIMESTAMP`. So becsuse the default order is ascending, the `-1` makes the order to descending.

Comment: Is there any way for me to get them first and then take the further actions?

Comment: Regardind your first question, please take o look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281855/how-to-read-childrens-from-a-firebase-database-using-firebaselistadapter-in-java). And for the second, please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android) at Frank van Puffelen answer. Hope you can solve the problems.

Comment: I change the methods to get the whole data by using addValueEventListener and sort them. Then I put them in the recycler adapter instead of using the firebaserecycleradapter. But I dun know that my way is good or not. Btw, Thank you for your help.